# Slick slider same navigation action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two slick sliders working well. Problem with the same navigation: **When I slide the first and second slide, the second slide will slide by 2 (like 1:2), at the same time the first slide will slide by one.**

I have tried with `asNavFor` but it has not split the slider1 and slider2 with the same navigation. Can anyone help me to achieve this? Solution will be marked sure.

```js
$('.slider1').slick({
  infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rows: 1,
    swipeToSlide: true,
 asNavFor: '.slider2'
});
 
 $('.slider2').slick({
   dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        arrows: true,
 asNavFor: '.slider1'
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
     color: black !important;
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e84a69;
}

.slick-prev {
    position: relative;
    top: 45px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <section class="slider slider1">
                <div>slide1</div>
                <div>slide2</div>
                <div>slide3</div>
                <div>slide4</div>
                <div>slide5</div>
                <div>slide6</div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <section class="slider slider2">
                <div>slide1</div>
                <div>slide2</div>
                <div>slide3</div>
                <div>slide4</div>
                <div>slide5</div>
                <div>slide6</div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want first slide will slide 1 and second slider will slide by 2 when both left and right click and drag.

Comment: it's very unclear what are you asking

Comment: I have two slider when I navigate first slide it will slide by 1 and second slide will slide by 2

Comment: @AbhishekPandey currently it will sliding 1/1. I want the second slider 2/2

Comment: The trick is to use `slidesToShow: 1.99` and `slidesToScroll: 1`. You got that because you've set the `slidesToShow` to 2.